# Spring Mutableacl always yield no permission after version upgrade

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-acl

We have recently performed a spring security version upgrade on our existing app. The spring security has been upgrade from version 2.0.4 to the latest version 5. So I believe its quite a big leap of version.

We have tuned all those spring xml config files, and updated all those spring package path accordingly (in all our java classes & xml config files that referring to spring classes).

The version upgrade seems done nicely, we able to run the app and login successfully. However we just noticed that the mutable ACL portion is now not working as expected. We use the spring mutable ACL to control each user's access on particular record. We have a custom mutable ACL implementation, and it works fine before the spring version upgrade. Sadly, now it always yield "no permission" where a user suppose to have required permission on the particular record.

Could someone shed some light on what we need to take note on / something necessary that I am not aware of, for the mutable ACL portion, in this version upgrade?

I am not attaching any snippet of code here, as I have no idea which part of code could be the root cause, the app just doesn't throw any exception. Unless I have to attach the entire project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I able resolve the issue. It was simply due to some stupid typo error in my syntax. After corrected the syntax, it is working fine now.